# Memory Error while iterating over 500 parquet files

Tags: pandas, dataframe, pycharm, python-3.6

I am trying to take about 500 parquet files as an Input for my model and when the code iterates at around 165, it comes out of the for loop and shows the error that its a memory error. I get a windows notification saying that your computer is low on memory.

I am using fastparquet as my engine to iterate over each single parquet files. Is there a turnaround for the same.[image]

EDIT:
I am giving the code which I used for the same:

```
for partition in range(3, 503):

    start_time = datetime.now()
    file_path = adl.ls(lrs_parquet_path)[partition]

    with adl.open(file_path, 'rb') as f, adl.open(
            str(output_preds_path) + "/preds_partition_" + str(partition) + ".csv", 'wb') as b:
        df = pd.read_parquet(f, engine='auto')

        df = utils.scoredf_preprocessing(df)
        scoreing_df = df[features]
        dtm = xgb.DMatrix(data=scoreing_df.drop('eu', axis=1), base_margin=np.log(scoreing_df['eu']))
        preds_ls.append(xgbmod.predict(dtm))
        actual_ls.append(df.agl_net_rcov_xcat_amt.values)
        print(partition, file_path)
```

Comment: I would look into `dask` as an alternative to pandas when memory is the bottleneck. It is designed to use most of the same methods as pandas, which makes it possible to transform your code from pandas to dask. It really depends on what methods you use, as not all pandas methods are supported.

Comment: Maybe, there is a way we can add a flag that when memory usage is at the maximum, save the predictions and again start the loop from where it stopped.